# Kotlin dagger ComponentProcessor was unable to process this interface, android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger

I have an existing project which is in Java
I am converting it to Kotlin and facing issue with Dagger. While with java the DI works perfect but with Kotlin getting error

```
ComponentProcessor was unable to process this class because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
public final class AppCMSNavItemsFragmentKt extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment {
```

This is my fragment

```
class AppCMSNavItemsFragmentKt : Fragment() {

@Inject
lateinit var appCMSPresenter: AppCMSPresenter

override fun onAttachFragment(childFragment: Fragment) {
    super.onAttachFragment(childFragment)
    (requireActivity().applicationContext as AppCMSApplication).appCMSPresenterComponent.inject(this)
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_nav, container, false)
}
}
```

This is the generated file for fragment

```
public final class AppCMSNavItemsFragmentKt extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment {
@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
@javax.inject.Inject()
public com.presenters.AppCMSPresenter appCMSPresenter;
private java.util.HashMap _$_findViewCache;

@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
public final com.presenters.AppCMSPresenter getAppCMSPresenter() {
    return null;
}

public final void setAppCMSPresenter(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
com.presenters.AppCMSPresenter p0) {
}

@java.lang.Override()
public void onAttachFragment(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
androidx.fragment.app.Fragment childFragment) {
}

@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable()
@java.lang.Override()
public android.view.View onCreateView(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
android.view.LayoutInflater inflater, @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable()
android.view.ViewGroup container, @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable()
android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return null;
}

public AppCMSNavItemsFragmentKt() {
    super();
}
}
```

This is my module

```
@Module(includes = {AppCMSSearchModule.class})
public class AppCMSPresenterModule {
@Provides
@Singleton
public ReferenceQueue<Object> providesReferenceQueue() {
    return new ReferenceQueue<>();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
public AppCMSPresenter providesAppCMSPresenter(Gson gson,
                                               AppCMSArticleCall appCMSArticleCall,
                                               AppCMSPhotoGalleryCall appCMSPhotoGalleryCall,
                                               AppCMSScheduleCall appCMSScheduleCall) {
    return new AppCMSPresenter(gson,
            appCMSArticleCall,
            appCMSPhotoGalleryCall,
            appCMSScheduleCall)
}

}
```

This is the component

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppCMSPresenterModule.class})
public interface AppCMSPresenterComponent {
AppCMSPresenter appCMSPresenter();

void inject(AppCMSPageActivity activity);

void inject(AppCMSPlayAudioActivity activity);

void inject(AppCMSPlayVideoActivity activity);

void inject(AppCMSNavItemsFragmentKt fragment);}
```

Can someone guide me what is the issue over here?

Comment: is `AppCMSPresenter` injectable ?

Comment: @Blackbelt yes it is , update with module and component in the question

Comment: and I assume also `Gson gson,
                                               AppCMSArticleCall appCMSArticleCall,
                                               AppCMSPhotoGalleryCall appCMSPhotoGalleryCall,
                                               AppCMSScheduleCall appCMSScheduleCall)` can be resolved with provides in different modules ?

Comment: @Blackbelt yes , this code works fine with Java Fragment / activity but with kotlin I am facing the issue